# Mishenichnas Adar marbin b'simcha

Tags: calendar, simchah-joy-happiness, masechet-taanis

The Gemorah says in Taanis 29a

> משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה
>
> When Adar comes in one should increase in Simcha (Joy).

What does this mean exactly? What should one do to "increase" ("marbin") in Simcha? What's an example? (Please give sources as always.)